# Spring MVC Controller: Разница между return forward, redirect, и возвратом jsp-файла

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, java, http, java-ee

Не понимаю, что использовать и когда.
Есть две страницы - intro.jsp(1) и booksList.jsp(2). Для каждой страницы создано по одному классу-контроллеру.

На первой странице есть кнопка, открывающая вторую странцу:

```
<form method="GET" action="/request-list">
        <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**Первый вопрос**: не уверен насчёт правильности этой кнопки - она вроде работает OK, но как сделать правильно, чтобы при открытии не было вопросительного знака на конце URL.

**Второе**: 
Когда происходит нажатие на кнопку (кнопка на первой странице), срабатывает метод с аннотацией (контроллер для первой страницы):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "request-list")
```

А вот класс-контроллер, который отвечает за действия со второй страницей:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books")
@Controller
public class BooksListController {

    /**
     * запрос на страницу-список
     */
    @RequestMapping
    public String booksList() {
        return "jsp/books/booksList";
    }

}
```

А что возвращать этим методом? То есть как мне делать переход из первой на вторую страницу? 
Как писать:

- `return "redirect:/books";` вернул  `http://localhost:8080/books?`
- `return "jsp/books/booksList";` вернул `http://localhost:8080/request-list?`
- `return "forward:/books";` вернул `http://localhost:8080/request-list?`

Вроде бы результат одинаков (страница 2 открывается), ну кроме URL в браузере - они разные.
Для каких случаев что использовать?

Comment: **forward** - это серверный переход на другой контроллер
**redirect** - отправляет http с кодом 302 и происходит редирект на другой url.

Второй применяют частенько как защиту от F5.
Скажем при оплате чтобы та повторно не происходила.

Comment: SO я уже начитался и написано там тоже самое. Правильно ли я понимаю что redirect нужно использовать после POST-запроса?

Comment: Да. См. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get